# Probability of One Random Variable Less than Another -- Why is this approach Wrong?

Tags: probability

This is not for homework. Just my curiosity. I am wondering why the following approach does not work.

Question: If $X_1, X_2$ have CDFs $F_{X_1},F_{X_2}$ respectively and are independent. What is $P(X_1\geq X_2)$?

Proposed Answer: $P(X_1\geq X_2) = \int F_{X_2}(t)dF_{X_1}(t)$

I know what the correct answer is, but I guess I just want to understand why the above answer is wrong. My friend is very sure it is incorrect but can't explain why not adequately. I've seen an answer to this question that suggests the same thing on another post but it was down voted, so that gives me further confidence that it is wrong. That being said, it's not obvious to me why it is...

Comment: Assuming the distributions have densities you would integrate the joint densities (in this case the product of the 2) but only in the region where $X_1$ >$X_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your expression is correct:** Since $X_1 \ \bot \ X_2$ we can use a [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) to write the probability of interest as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \geqslant X_2) 
&= \mathbb{P}(X_2 \leqslant X_1) \\[6pt]
&= \int \mathbb{P}(X_2 \leqslant X_1 | X_1 = t) \ d F_{X_1}(t) \\[6pt]
&= \int \mathbb{P}(X_2 \leqslant t) \ d F_{X_1}(t) \\[6pt]
&= \int F_{X_2}(x) \ d F_{X_1}(t). \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Comment: rigorous treatment! Are you sure it is $P(X_1\leq X_2)$ since the integral in the question uses $dF_{X_1}$, not $dF_{X_2}$?

Comment: @gunes: I misread the subscripts in the question - now edited.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was looking for a general proof of this, so I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems correct to me, because what you write is actually $\int F_{X_2}(t)f_{X_1}(t)dt$ and can be interpreted as swiping $t$ values such that when $X_1$ is equal to $t$, we consider all $X_2$ smaller than $t$; applying the total probability law gives us $P(X_2\leq X_1)\approx\sum_t P(X_2\leq t)P(X_1=t)$, which makes sense.

An example: let $X_1\sim\exp(\lambda),X_2\sim\exp(\mu)\rightarrow F_{X_2}(t)=1-e^{-\mu t}$, $dF_{X_1}(t)=\lambda e^{-\lambda t}dt$. Then, the integral becomes:
$$P(X_2\leq X_1)=\int_0^\infty (1-e^{-\mu t})\lambda e^{-\lambda t}dt=1-\lambda\int_0^\infty e^{-(\lambda+\mu)t}dt=\frac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$$
which can be found via joint PDF directly as in @MichaelChernick's comment:
$$P(X_2\leq X_1)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^{x_1}\lambda\mu e^{-\mu x_2}e^{-\lambda x_1}dx_2dx_1=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\lambda e^{-\lambda x_1}(1-e^{-\mu x_1})dx_{1}}_{\text{above integral}}$$

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation at the beginning mirrors the intuition I had when I came up with the equality yesterday. My friend tends to be better at this stuff than I am, but after showing him your post, he's convinced that it actually is alright. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I had to accumulate enough reputation to upvote and I just acquired that today. Thanks again for your help.